# Filter entries using form

Tags: html, json, forms, twitter-bootstrap, expressionengine

I have an ExpressionEngine site that I'm building with Bootstrap. It's a site for volunteers to find projects to help with. On the home page I have a modal with a form for them to select when they're available and what categories of jobs they're looking for. Then they can click submit and it'll go to a new page with filtered entries.

I don't know if this is possible using the GET method or POST method on the form. I've figured out how to use the GET method and get a query string into my URL but I don't know how to use that data to filter my entries on the entries page. Or would using POST and JSON be a better option? I don't know really how to implement either so any help would be great.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: P.S. I can post code if it'd help. I'm developing it locally currently or I'd post a link.

Comment: Yes, please post the code if you can, both here and jsfiddle.  Using http://www.jsfiddle.com is usually pretty efficient.

Comment: @JoshBeam here's my fiddle. Hopefully that helps. http://jsfiddle.net/3shxg/ 

I'm looking into the method that you've recommended. I've got some reading to do!

Comment: Okay, I checked it out.  I see that you just have the HTML markup.  There is no scripting, though, which makes it so that none of your HTML is actually going to "do" anything.

Comment: @JoshBeam Thanks for looking it over! Unfortunately I haven't figured that part out yet. I don't really know how to go about scripting it at this point so I'll have to do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the information you would like to show is stored.

If you are using MySQL (a common RDMS), or any other form of SQL Database for that matter, the most common way is to send your GET query string (for example) to your server, have a sever-side language (such as PHP) handle that request by accessing your database, and then echo the result.  This can be done synchronously, or with AJAX.

For example, the flow of everything might look like this:

1. User selects an option (say, "Gardening Projects").
2. JavaScript converts the value of that input option to a query string and sends an HTTP request using the GET method.
3. The destination of this request is "filter.php" (for example).
4. "filter.php" access your database using an SQL query, which searches for any entries in your database, say, having a tag of "gardening".
5. "filter.php" echos a statement with those entries (or, better yet, returns a JSON object)
6. JavaScript then parses the resultant JSON object into the DOM, which displays as a bunch of links in a result area that your user can click on.

The question you have about how to handle this is very broad, so I would recommend simply doing some Google searches or looking around this site for resources that show you how to set up databases, access those databases with possibly PHP/SQL, and maybe even use AJAX to return those results, etc.

To get you started (these are in no particular order):

1. [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)
2. [PHP - JSON encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode)
3. [SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)
4. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out with some help from @JoshBeam. It turns out that I was trying to make it way more complicated than it actually is. Rookie mistake. In the end I just ended up using `method=get` in my form and the setting the action as the page with the filtered entries. I then used php to echo the inputs into my EE channel:entries tag.

One thing I still haven't figured out is how to make it so that my query string will combine values for matching names. Currently I have checkboxes for days of the week, each with `name="day"` and different values for each day. If there are multiple checked, my query string becomes example.com/?day=sun&day=mon when I'd rather have it as example.com/?day=sun&mon. So if anyone has any tips on that, I'd welcome them! I also wonder if there's a way to add pipes between each value when I echo them in my EE tag so that I can have multiples - e.g. `{exp:channel:entries category="1|2|3"}`. But I have really yet to Google either of these questions so I'll do that.

Thanks!